# django Ordering a field with user signed in

Tags: django, django-templates

I am a newbee in Django, And I am trying to alter one of my view to order by the user signed in. For example, If 'test@example.com' is  signed in,  then the Tview should give data related to Test@example.com in the first row. At the moment it is in no specific order.

```
Current order: for a user signed as  test@example.com
    GEL_TEACT trea@example.com
    TREAT_ACT test@example.com

    I want to order this as:

    Product OWNER
    TREAT_ACT test@example.com
    GEL_TEACT trea@example.com
```

my View:

```
class PListView(ListView):
    model = Product

    template_name = "app/product_list.html"

project_list_view = PListView.as_view()
```

my template:

```
<tbody>
                {% for product in object_list %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{% url "product-detail" pro_id=project.pk %}">{{ product.title }}</a></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{% url "product-update" project_id=project.pk %}">
                            <i class="fi-pencil"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}

            </tbody>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

These are three different options, depending on what you need. Just use one of them.

In your example, a logged in user should be displayed first. That is just one item to put in front of the list. So its easiest to do that right in the template

```
<ul>
<li>{{ user.username }}</a></li>
{% for item in users %}
  {% if item != user %}
    <li>{{ item.username }}</a></li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However, if you want to get the list in a particular order, there are two ways to achieve that. If the order is just for this one ListView, then use [the `get_queryset()` method of ListView()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)

```
class PListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "app/product_list.html"

    get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.all().order_by('name')
```

However, if the data should *always* be ordered in this way, on all lists of the Product model, you can [order it right on the model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#ordering) instead

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name', ]
```